# How to run .qvw (qlikview) file through Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, qlikview

I want to run .qvw file through Jenkins.

To Run a qlikview file I am using batch file it is working fine  ,I am using below command in batch file
"path\qv.exe" /r "path\myapplication.qvw"

This command is reloading my application ,I want to do it by Jenkins.
Has anyone done this before.

When I am trying to run above batch command through jenkins job it is continuously running.

"path\qv.exe" /r "path\myapplication.qvw"

Answer (score 0):

Probably it remains open. You can try to add trigger to run macro which close app after reload:

[image: find trigger settings here]

VBScript Macro to save and close app is:

```
sub SaveQuit

    ActiveDocument.Save
    ActiveDocument.GetApplication.Quit

end sub
```

If you are using QlikView server/publisher better use reload from QMC there.

Comment: No, above mentioned commands opens, reload nd closes the application.and I can not see application is open anywhere.

Comment: Maybe try to specify session in Jenkins so you will see what is going on (it can be also in separate session 0). Under Jenkins probably you use psexec for reloading so it should be such a code:
 "C:\Qlikview\PROD APPLICATION\modules\scripts\edx\PsExec64.exe" \\SERVER_NAME -u DOMAIN\user -p password -i 1 -d -high cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\QlikView\qv.exe" /r "path\myapplication.qvw"

Comment: we can not go with this way because this will require password for each users.we have to make it dynamic.

Comment: Got the solution. just go to services.msc and log on as a administrator  then in jenkins  create a project and call a batch command having below command, 
"path\qv.exe" /r "path\myapplication.qvw".It will do the job.

Comment: Hi Shivam, what is the step to solve this issue? As you mention go to services.msc and log on as a administrator . Do we need to start any service? What is the detail steps?

Answer (score 0):

One option may be to have VBS for opening, reloading, saving and closing, like OpenSaveClose.vbs provided below.
Then you can use it in CMD files: wscript OpenSaveClose.vbs QvDoc.qvw

```
REM OpenSaveClose.vbs
Dim MyApp, MyDoc
Set MyApp = CreateObject("QlikTech.QlikView")
Set MyDoc = MyApp.OpenDocEx(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0),0,False)
MyDoc.GetApplication.WaitforIdle
REM MyDoc.Reload or whatever
MyDoc.SaveAs(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
MyDoc.GetApplication.WaitforIdle
MyDoc.CloseDoc
MyApp.Sleep 2000
MyApp.Quit
Set MyDoc = Nothing
Set MyApp = Nothing
```