# Open and run .qvw (qlikview) file through Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, qlikview, jenkins-cli

To Run a qlikview file I am using batch file it is working fine ,I am using below command in batch file "path\qv.exe" /r "path\myapplication.qvw"

When I am trying to run above batch command through jenkins job it is continuously running.

"path\qv.exe" /r "path\myapplication.qvw"

The related post is here
[How to run .qvw (qlikview) file through Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385768/how-to-run-qvw-qlikview-file-through-jenkins)

THe sulution is  just go to services.msc and log on as a administrator then in jenkins create a project and call a batch command having below command, "path\qv.exe" /r "path\myapplication.qvw".It will do the job.

Question:  go to services.msc for what?
what is the detail steps to solution this issus:jenkins job it is continuously running.

Answer (score 0):

Go to services.msc and select the Jenkins service  and log on the Jenkins service  as a administrator in the Jenkins service log on page.
In jenkins create a project and call a batch command having below command, "path\qv.exe" /r "path\myapplication.qvw".It will do the job
[image]